# iTunes search API releaseDate data conflicts with track release date in iTunes store

Tags: api, search, itunes

Are there two release dates in the API? I notice that releaseDate doesn't always match up with what is displayed in iTunes.

For example, an api search in the Great Britain store for Dreadlock Holiday by 10CC, looking at the 'Bloody Tourists' album shows the release date as 2002-07-15T07:00:00Z, yet the store says Sep 1978 (the latter being correct).

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=dreadlock+holiday&country=GB

Is there another date to access?

Answer (score 0):

The date possibly when the item was released on iTunes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).